# raise_application_error issue in Oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER del_info
   BEFORE DELETE
   ON emp
   REFERENCING NEW AS new OLD AS old
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
   IF :old.ename = 'GAU'
   THEN
      INSERT INTO audit_table (who, dated)
           VALUES (USER, TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));

      COMMIT;
      raise_application_error (
         -20001,
         'You Are not authorized to delete this record');
   ELSE
      NULL;
   END IF;
END;
```

There is a problem here. It works fine if I delete any user using where clause, but if I fire query like delete from emp, then it gives problems, that is it does not delete any records. The ideal behaviour should be, it should not delete that single recors(ename = 'GAU'), rest all should be deleted. Please help

Comment: As vav says, omit that record from the original DELETE query. You can do that by disallowing direct deletes (e.g. a procedure) or by hiding the table behind a view. Another method is to use VPD to stop the record being seen by the delete statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can't accept part of the transaction and raise error on another part.

Workaround: Phoenix mode!

Once record is deleted, insert it back.

Better aproach:

1. revoke rights to DELETE
2. write a procedure to provide delete functionality. That procedure will always exclude "permanent" record.
3. grant users permission to execute that procedure

3rd solution:

1. write a view that would exclude "permanent" record. You may add WITH CHECK OPTION to prohibit insertion of another "permanent" record.
2. grant users DELETE on that view

More on how to use/not use triggers is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html)

Comment: I am not allowed to use view since the table is referred multiple times by application front end. The problem is that, there is this particular user that is getting mysteriously deleted at random occasions. So the requirement is creation of a trigger that: 1. Restrict that particular row from deletion 2. keep time and user details in an audit table whenever deletion is attempted, only on that particular record. all other table records should be left alone(no restriction from any deletion). But this trigger present problems when I use 'delete from table' syntax.

Comment: You can rename table and create view with tablename. That will be transparent for the application.

Comment: You can use audit plus "phoenix mode", just don't raise an exception in this case.